# интегралы в Matlab

Tags: matlab

Matlab не хочет считать интеграл, с самим интегралом всё хорошо, но в ответ он просто выводит непосчитанный интеграл(

С этим можно что-то сделать, или придётся смириться?

Comment: +1 за слово "смериться"

Comment: Судя по вопросу, придется смириться.

Answer (score 0):

Матлаб позволяет реализовать вычисления интегралов несколькими методами: правых и левых прямоугольников, трапеций и метод Симпсона.
Так как в вопросе не указан конкретный интеграл, предлагаю ознакомиться с примерами решений по всем методам:
https://codetown.ru/matlab/integraly/